# Call to Member function on Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I'm utilizing a for each to try to generate a menu dynamically from a MySQL database. Because there's more than one it will always return an array. I use multiple files to generate the menu.
I use a class to create the menu

```
class menu extends db{
       public function LoadMainMenu() {
       global $db;
       $query = <<<SQL
       SELECT id,name
       FROM menu
       WHERE enabled = :active
       AND location = :mainmenu
SQL;
       $resource = $db->sitedb->prepare( $query );
       $resource->execute( array(
       ':active'    => '1',
       ':mainmenu'  => '1',
));
foreach($resource as $row){
       echo '<li><a href="viewPage?pageid='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></li>';
   }
}
$menu = new menu();
```

My next file is my base.class.php file

```
function LoadMainMenu() {
global $menu;
$menu->LoadMainMenu();
}
```

Then I have my index.php file within my theme settings where I have it called

```
<ul class='topmenu'>
<?php LoadMainMenu(); ?>
</ul>
```

It then gives me the error that it's a call to a member function on an array on base.class.php; If anymore code would help please let me know.

Comment: Well where do you instantiate `$menu` and does `base.class.php` have access to the said file. It's also general best practice to avoid using the `global`

Comment: base.class.php includes all subclass.php files (Which menu.subclass.php is part of)  $menus is instantiated at the end of the menu.subclass.php file. The reason I have the global defined within base.class.php is because if I don't none of my classes seem to transfer over to the index theme file.

Comment: https://github.com/Doxramos/DoxramosCMS There's a link to the core that I have so far. It works just fine to pull template information, so I'm really at a lost as to why it's having any issues with menus.

Comment: Turns out that I can change it to `public function GetMainMenu() { echo "Test"; }` And it still returns the same output, so now I'm even more confused then I was before.

Comment: This is likely due to a naming collision, which is why [global variables are bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/9457). However, the [code sample](/help/mcve) is not representative and the issue can't be reproduced from it.

Answer (score 0):

Not Really an end all cure all, but it works. I added it within the db.class.php and then just added `global $db` and then called `$db->GetMainMenu()` within the main index.php Template and it seems to have worked. Other than that I'm not sure what else to do.